# UFT 12.01 ".click" and "FireEvent" doesn't work

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, qtp, hp-uft

I had an already successful running code but after some application maintenance/deployment. The same code doesn't work. Now the problem is that the same code works on different system.

I have a code - `Browser("").Page("").WebElement("").click`- which used to run earlier but now it doesn't. The properties have remained the same and highlights when highlighted, while executing it goes to the application but doesn't click. The same is the case for `FireEvent`.

I have tried different methods to work around it like - using *ChildObjects* and using *Replay Type* as Mouse instead of *Event*.

It works with *Replay Type* but **UFT** crashes when *Replay Type* is changed back to *Event*.

Anyway I am curious to know, how the same code works on different machine without having to do any workaround and it doesn't on mine.
Both the system run **UFT 12.01**, one having **IE 11** (where it doesn't work), second having **IE 8** (Where it works).

Does it have to with IE version ? As I read somewhere that these events are related to the *DOM*.

Appreciate your thoughts/Inputs here

Comment: Is there any error message you are getting or have you tried to debug the code...?

Comment: @Nelly27281 - I have tried to debug the code, it gets the application in focus so I am guessing it executes the line but there is no effect. about the error message - there are none, even on the result page it shows as "Done"

Comment: Just to check, is BHOManager Class Add-ons, enabled or disabled...?

Comment: It was disabled, but I have enabled it but still no result - if that had to with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
'Runs mouse operations using the mouse
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2

Browser("").Page("").WebElement("").click

'Back to running mouse operations using browser events
Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 1
```

Comment: Thanks but I had already tried this solution before posting the question :), what happens is that when I change the replay type from "2" to "1" UFT crashes. Appreciate your answer though

Comment: I can't help you more as I've not used IE 11 yet. So, best of luck.

Comment: I think it has to do something with DOM, I will try to dig deep. Thanks for your help though