# Unable to perform an event on a Web button even though the system identifies the object in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

Unable to perform an event on a Web button even though the system identifies the object in UFT.
I have already tried changing the Replace type to the value "mouse" and also tried using Fire Event. Please help me find the issue here.

Comment: What version of IE are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post [UFT 12.01 ".click" and "FireEvent" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31517699/uft-12-01-click-and-fireevent-doesnt-work)

it could be many reasons, what worked for me was using IE 8.

Let me know if this works